# Dynamic memory allocation in game server

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, boost-asio

I currently write MMO server.
And I now have dynamic memory allocation for incoming packet (first read 8 byte header, after allocate memory for body and read body in Packet API class).
But I heard that dynamic memory allocation is slow.
And now, should I stay with dynamic memory alloc (i perform read/write operations with boost asio async) or should I transform it to fixed size ?
Biggest packet size used in my model is 5824 bytes, and i don't think so using static buffer with that value will be good.
Thanks.

Comment: Allocating for each packet from the heap will be slow.  Allocating a large chunk from memory, and then handing out pieces of it per packet will be faster.

Comment: 5824 should be fine for a stack-allocated array. Also, you've tagged this `c++`, you should probably be using `std::vector`, `std::array` and friends.

Comment: Which is faster your computer or your internet connection? I suggest profiling it first then apply any necessary changes to increase performance.

Comment: I would suggest you teach yourself how to test the theory that it is slow, and verify whether or not it is. That said, there is a reason that allocators like [SmartHeap](http://www.microquill.com/smartheap/), [JEMalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/) and [Google-Perftools](https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/) exist.

Comment: Many high-performance, multi-threaded, network-oriented servers avoid the system allocator as a matter of portability. Not all system allocators are created equal and some just do not perform well in a busy, multi-threaded environment, primarily because their resources are behind a simple mutex lock/unlock.

Of course, an equally large part of problem is often, ime, badly written code which allocs and frees like there's no tomorrow putting all that contention on the allocator.

Comment: I suggest not using dynamic memory allocation because it may lead to memory leaks.  You can overwrite an array rather than reallocating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the real world, dynamic allocation is slower than automatic allocation.  That's true -- at least in general.

That doesn't mean that dynamic allocation is *too slow*.  The only way to determine that is to profile your code.  Until you have done that, it is impossible to say that you should abandon dynamic allocation because it is too slow.

That's not to say your choice to use dynamic allocation was the right choice.  .  There are reasons other than performance why dynamic allocation is often a dish best left unserved.  You should understand the nature of memory allocation, the reasons to allocate memory in a particular way, and the pros and cons of each before settling on your design.

In C++, the default allocation method should usually be automatic allocation until you have a reason to use some other method.

There are a lot of "I heard this" and "I don't think that" in your question.  Software engineering isn't about guessing and rumors.  It's about rigor and logic.  Test your code.  Identify bottlenecks.  Fix problems that you know about.